# Does ExternalInterface work locally on an Android device?

Tags: javascript, android, flash

Ok, I am doing a simple ExternalInterface call to hit up a JavaScript function. It works perfect in every browser on a desktop, both on a web server and locally with the file:// protocol by setting allowscriptaccess to always.

The problem is, my client has to have this running offline on an Android tablet or phone. Now, it works fine when it points to the web server from the tablet, but when I try to run it locally the ExternalInterface call never fires.

I am using the Dolphin HD browser as well as the built in browser on the device.

So my main questions are, because this works everywhere else, I am assuming Flash on Android does not allow EI calls when running locally for whatever reason?  Is there a workaround? Do fsCommands work locally?